# Pagination in Panelizer drupal

Tags: paging, panels

I'm using [panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) and [panelizer](https://www.drupal.org/project/panelizer). I created a custom content in panelizer where I can *upload* a file. When I render the results, I have a lot of items. Now I want to paginate them.

How can I add the *pagination* in *panelizer* or use a *view in panelizer*?

Answer (score 0):

[Pagerer](https://www.drupal.org/project/pagerer)

> **Features:**
>
> - multi-pane pager
> - Views pager plugin
> - control whether to display links to pages, to items, or to item ranges
> - direct input of the page to go to through an input widget
> - selection of the page to go to through a jQuery UI slider
> - selection of the page to go to through a client-side scrolling pager
> - links to progressively more distant pages (like +10, + 20, +100, +200)
> - adaptive logic links
> - specify text to be used to render page separators (like a vertical bar) and page breakers (like an ellipsis)
> - supports Views' AJAX enabled pager

Comment: And how does it answers the question? There is no mention of it working with panels or panelizer in piece you quoted. If you just *know* it works, write a paragraph or two about that.

Comment: multi-pane pager,Views pager plugin using this you do it